# Increase VS Augment

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between “increase” and “augment”? I read that “Increase” is related to quantity meanwhile “augment” is related to quality, but at the same time I found a lot of sentences in which “augment” is used meaning “increase”.

Examples/

1) Because I want to augment my income,I’m thinking about getting a second job.

2) The budget was augmented by various donations.

Comment: There are two good answers below. But the idea that "augment" precludes any concept of an increase in quantity is simply absurd. Do you have a citation? I want to go sneer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-increase-and-augment.                                 https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/augment-increase.5263/

Answer (score 1):

Compare the intransitive versions of both verbs:

*The harder they worked, the more their harvests increased.* - correct

*The harder they worked, the more their harvests augmented.* - wrong.

But in the transitive form:

*The harder they worked, the more their harvests increased their wealth.* - correct

*The harder they worked, the more their harvests augmented their wealth.* - correct.

It is possible to use “to augment” as an intransitive verb, but it is not common:

> 2010   Hudson Review 63 142   *Their numbers began to augment as soon as Paris was selected as the seat of government.*

To increase implies **a growth** (sudden or over time) in size.

To augment implies **to add to**; we cannot always replace "grow" with "augment".

The nouns are useful in order to see the differences:

An **augmentation** adds something to an object; an **increase** causes the original object to be bigger:

> Proceedings of the IEEE and ACM International Symposium on Augmented Reality (2001) *The video images are augmented (=added to) with the live images from the ultrasound scanner.*

In the transitive form of the verb, there is a **lot** of overlap in the meanings and any real difference is subtle - more of a nuance.

**1** Augment is in a higher register/more formal than "increase" and

**2** is chiefly used with something that has a positive effect and

**3** often (but not always), as you say, related to a quality.

**4** Increase is neutral and far commoner in general use.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that "augment" is transitive only. But it can cover both quantity and quality:

[Merriam-Webster "augment"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment)
to make greater, more numerous, larger, or more intense

The word "increase" has intransitive uses, for example,

"The need for medical care has increased in recent years."

Comment: @JackOFlaherty Thank you!